# Survival regression variance estimates

Tags: r, regression, survival, regression-coefficients, censoring

I would like help understanding why a survival regression with no censored
data-points does not give the same variance estimates as a linear model
(see code below).

I think it must be something to do with the fact that the variance is an
actual parameter in the survival version via the log(scale), and possibly
that different assumptions are made about the distribution of the variance.
But I really don't know, I'm just guessing.

The reason I ask is because I am moving a process, that has always been
modelled using a linear model, to a survival model (because there are
sometimes a few censored data points). In the past, the censored data
points have been treated as missing which imparts bias. The variance of the
estimates in this process is key, so I need to know why they are changing
in this systematic way?!

```
library(survival)

ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
ctl.surv <- Surv(ctl)

trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)

lmod <- lm     (ctl      ~ trt                )
smod <- survreg(ctl.surv ~ trt,dist="gaussian")

coef(lmod)
coef(smod) # same

vcov(lmod)
vcov(smod) # smod is smaller

diag(vcov(lmod))     /
diag(vcov(smod))[1:2]  # 1.25 == 0.5*(n/(n-1))

( summary(lmod)$coef [   ,"Std. Error"] /
      summary(smod)$table[1:2,"Std. Error"]   )^2    # 1.25 = 0.5*(n/(n-1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two models is essentially due to maximum likelihood estimates of $\sigma$ (survreg) vs. unbiased estimates (lm).

In particular, lm uses the unbiased estimator $\hat s = \frac{\hat \sigma \sqrt n}{\sqrt{(n-k)}}$, where $\hat \sigma$ is the MLE and $k$ is the number of mean parameters estimated.

On the other hand, survreg uses the MLE estimate of $\sigma$. As far as I know, there is little choice in this matter; I'm not aware of an unbiased estimator for $\sigma$ in the case on censored data.

Answer (score 0):

The `lm`-function would estimate the line where `trt` was the x-predictor and `ctl` was the y-outcome:

> png(); plot(trt ~ ctl)
>   abline(lmod <- lm     (ctl      ~ trt                ), col='red')
>   dev.off()

[image]

The `survreg`-function would order the times in Surv() and use the number of "surviving" cases as a denominator to estimate hazard rates as a function of trt values (which would appear to make very little sense.). I cannot understand why you think these should deliver similar results.

Comment: They will (and do) give similar results because the distribution assumed in the survival model is Gaussian and none of the observations are censored. It is the same model, however the method of estimation is different. If you take the above code and increase the sample size, they will asymptotically reach the same parameter estimates

Comment: The data make it appear that you are examining two different groups (trt and ctl) and measuring a time value for the individual units in each group. That was the basis for my concern that neither `lm((ctl   ~ trt  )` nor `smod <- survreg(ctl.surv ~ trt,dist="gaussian")` appeared to be an appropriate model. If you wnat good statistical advice you will need to describe the data gathering process and the goals of hte study better.

Comment: Apologies for the dataset choice, it does seem that I am comparing control and treatment groups. You could imagine a case where there is a chance that only the treatment group observations were censored therefore this model could be appropriate. In actual fact, the data gathering process was just using the ?lm example dataset in R as I thought people would be familiar with it.

Comment: @sqrt: Do you now understand why neither `lm` nor `survreg` models you proposed have a meaningful interpretation? Both are regression models where you might compare those two sets of times by a factor covariate. It's completely wrong to use the `trt`-vector as a covariate..

Comment: No I don't understand. The variable names were taken from a standard R example and do not correspond to control and treatment. However, it is possible to imagine a crossover study giving data like this. It is also possible to imagine that one of the measurements (in this case: treated) can sometimes be censored and a model such as this might be appropriate. Note that the response for a survival model does not need to represent time, it can be anything with any type of censoring

Comment: The point here is that they are both outcome variables. There's no reason that trt should be a predictor of ctl. If the question is whether their means are different, then use a t.test. If the question is whetehr they might be different in a censored context, then associate them properly with a factor variable and put both trt and ctl in a  a Surv object using a model having that factor variable on the right.

Comment: I think all I can do is agree to disagree and point you to the accepted answer that interpreted the question is the way I hoped.